# How to add a series of img tags to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding to an array a url each time I click on checkbox

```
  $("body").on("change", ".grid .thumbnail :checkbox", function() {
    var urls = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        urls.push($(this).next("label").find("img").attr("src"));
    });
    $("#usp-custom-4").val("<img src=" + urls.join(">"));
  });
```

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
<img src="img.jpg">
<img src="img2.jpg">
```

This line is where my issue is:

```
$("#usp-custom-4").val("<img src=" + urls.join(">"));
```

I was trying to modify this other line I had:

```
$("#txtarea").val("<li>" + urls.join("</li><li>") + "</li>");
```

Currently by clicking on 2 checkboxes I am having :

```
<img src=img.jpg>img2.jpg
```

I am having no *`" "`* in the `src` and the second img isn't within a `src` and `img` tag

Comment: Why not just create an `img` element using `createElement` or JQuery, change the src, then append it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
$('body').on('change', '.grid .thumbnail :checkbox', function () {
  var urls = [
  ];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    urls.push($(this).next('label').find('img').attr('src'));
  });
  var str = '';
  urls.forEach(function (url) {
    str += '<img class="image-add" src="' + url + '"/>';
  });
  $('#usp-custom-4').val(str);

  // toggle check/unchecked via class
  $('.image-add').click(function () {
    var ele = $(this);
    var isChecked = ele.attr('checked');
    if (isChecked != 'true') {
      ele.addClass('checked');
      ele.attr('checked', 'true');
    } 
    else {
      ele.removeClass('checked');
      ele.attr('checked', 'false');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you are having a closing ) on this line  str += '<img src="' + url + '"/>');

Comment: one more thing, is it there a way to add / removewe check or uncheck? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/u9myz270/

Comment: Simething like this? hope it still helps!